# How to write ROW_NUMBER in Crystal Reports?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, ssms

I was wondering if I can use ROW_NUMBER in a formula in Crystal Reports?
Here is my part code that I wrote in SSMS SQL.

```
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BEDSIDE_UA_CSN ORDER BY UA_TIME) AS "SESSION_NUMBER"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any valid sql can be used in crystal reports. There are two ways you can use.

First way is you can directly use `add commnad` while creating the database connection.

Second way is you can write in `SQL expression fields` inside reports but in this way you need to enclose the sql inside `()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a sql server source for your report then , yes any valid sql should be OK

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Crystal Enterprise and a BOBJ universe, you may be limited to functions that the Data Federator recognizes (RANK and PERCENT_RANK). You might be able to use RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER.